# Import can't my import entity product class

Tags: magento, import

I've added a new product type to my magento installation called "book". For this matter, i've created a module under local pool. Let's suppose this module is called MyNameSpace/Producttypes.
Now i want to import some "books" to the store.

I've modified my config.xml so i have it like

```
<global>
...
    <importexport module="producttypes">
        <import_product_types>
            <book>producttypes/import_entity_product_type_book</book>
        </import_product_types>
    </importexport>
...
</global>
```

Further more, i've added my new class:

> MyNameSpace_Producttypes_Model_Import_Entity_Product_Type_Book

But when i try to import i always get an "Invalid entity model" error.

Debugging it, i've got an exception saying 
    Warning: include(Mage/Producttypes/Model/Import/Entity/Product/Type/Book.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in [...]/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

So, the question: why is trying to find my class under "Mage" namespace instead of mine? Do I need something else in my config?

Answer (score 0):

Your class is called `*_Bookable`, but you have `*_book` in your config XML.

Comment: @CarlosRevillo: paste the rest of your config.xml, or at the very least your global -> models node. Also give us a full path to your class (case sensitive, so don't type it manually).

Comment: don't worry, i just solved it. i modified the xml a bit so now i have
 <book>mynamespace_producttypes/import_entity_product_type_book</book>